# Can't access "props" from mapsDispatchToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to pass an input value from my component to a function in my redux actions. I am able to get the value in the function props. However, the props aren't passing into the `return dispatch =>` function. Is there any way to accomplish this goal?

#### actions.js

```
function fetchData(url){
  return fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(console.log())
}

export function getFilteredCharacters(input) {
  console.log(input); //Shows props in console
  return (dispatch) => {

    console.log(chars); //Doesn't show props in console
    for (let i=1; i<=9; i++) {
      requests.push(fetchData('https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=' + i));
    }

    Promise.all(requests)
    .then(data => {
      let charactersAll = [];
      let characterFiltered = [];
      for (let i=0; i<=8; i++) {
        charactersAll.push(...data[i].results);
      }
      for (let i=0; i < charactersAll.length; i++) {
        if (charactersAll[i].name.includes(input)) { // This is where I need the props.
          characterFiltered.push(charactersAll[i]);
        }
      }
      dispatch(setFilteredCharacters(characterFiltered));
    })
  }
}

export function setFilteredCharacters(characterFiltered) {
  return {
    type: SET_CHARACTERS_FILTERED,
    characterFiltered
  }
}
```

#### components/FilterInput.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getFilteredCharacters } from '../reducer/character/actions';


const FilterInput = ({ setFilter }) => {

  return (
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">Name</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" aria-label="Name" className="form-control" onChange={e => getFilteredCharacters(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  )
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getFilteredCharacters(input) {}
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(FilterInput);
```

Thanks to anyone for insight.

Comment: This part: `console.log(chars); //Doesn't show props in console`. Do you mean `console.log(input)`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. It was solved below I set up my mapDispatchToProps incorrectly. :doh:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct way

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getFilteredCharacters: (input)=>dispatch(getFilteredCharacters(input))
});
```

Or simply

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {getFilteredCharacters}
```

Currently you are calling to getFilteredCharacters directly inside FilterInput. Add a props argument for it

```
const FilterInput = ({ setFilter, getFilteredCharacters }) => {
//...
}
```